# How do I trump chrome's user agent stylesheet selector "-internal-autofill-selected"?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser

## Issue

I am applying a class "error" to an input tag when a user changes the text in the textbox. This class is used to change the background color of the textbox and keep a record of what has been changed. This works perfectly in other browsers, but when a user selects an option from an autofill box in chrome, the class is still applied, but chrome's user agent style still trumps my style, preventing the correct background color from being applied.

To make matters more confusing, when I inspect the page and look at computed styles, chrome strikes through the style that should be overridden, but still says that it is the style being applied:

[image: chrome computed properties]

---

## I Have Tried

- increasing the specificity of my style rule.
- overwriting chromes selector (this throws a warning that ":-internal-autofill-selected" is not a valid pseudo-class):

  ```
  input:-internal-autofill-selected{
      background-color: none !important;
  }
  ```
- Edge and Firefox (works as intended)
- Clearing the cache, restarting the browser (although, maybe I missed something?)
- one solution I found was to disable autofill for the page, but that will not work because autofill is very helpful for this textbox

## Reproducible Code

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ChangeColorRed(e) {
            e.target.classList.add("error");
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var txtboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (var j = 0; j < txtboxes.length; j++) {
                txtboxes[j].addEventListener('input', ChangeColorRed);
            }
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        #txtOrderNumber.error, #txtItem.error{
            background-color:#FFCCCB !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        Order Number:
        <input type="text" id="txtOrderNumber" class="form-control inputText"/>
        Item#:
        <input type="text" id="txtItem" class="form-control inputText"/>
        <input type="submit" name="btnSelect" value="Select" id="btnSelect" class="btn btn-secondary"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

I suspect the answer to this is either something really simple that I am missing or some strange chrome phantom error. Any insight into what I might be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

## UPDATE

CBroe supplied a workaround in the comments that is the best solution so far. Updating the script to the code below, makes Chrome stop thinking this field was auto-filled

```
function ChangeColorRed(e) {
    e.target.classList.add("error");
}
function BackgroundColorWorkaround() {
    document.querySelector('#txtOrderNumber').value = document.querySelector('#txtOrderNumber').value
    document.querySelector('#txtItem').value = document.querySelector('#txtItem').value
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    var txtboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var j = 0; j < txtboxes.length; j++) {
        txtboxes[j].addEventListener('input', ChangeColorRed);
        txtboxes[j].addEventListener('blur', BackgroundColorWorkaround);
    }
});
```

Comment: Provide a [mre] of the issue first of all, please. (Yes, we _could_ perhaps create one ourselves, but that is not the point.)

Comment: @CBroe I have updated the question to contain reproducible code

Comment: Doesn’t look like Chrome is impressed with any attempts at overwriting this style here. Whatever selectors I try, it shows the specified background color in inspect via, and crosses out the one from the `input:-internal-autofill-selected` - yet it still _applies_ the latter. Even inline style applied directly to the element and with !important doesn’t seem able to change that.

Comment: The only thing that does seem to help, is make Chrome stop thinking this field was auto-filled – `document.querySelector('#txtItem').value = document.querySelector('#txtItem').value` typed into the browser console afterwards, makes your custom background color show up. Maybe you can apply that in combination with a blur event or something …

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for that nice little workaround. It seems to be working as a listener for blur.

Comment: The prevailing method in the wild seems to be to use an inset box-shadow which is drawn over the background. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/change-autocomplete-styles-webkit-browsers/ Problem is that transparent backgrounds are not possible, among other issues.

Comment: I worry that the JS-based solution of making Chrome think it's not autofill could cause issues with extensions or accessibility?